# linearization of a non linear system

Tags: matlab

Can Anyone help me in linearizing this system so that I can find the transfer function of the linear system? I want to do the simulation on this system in MATLAB.

[image: here are my nonlinear system equations]

Comment: If you're looking for a mathematical model you may have better luck at [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If `u` is a constant on the interval 0 to 1, the system is already linear.